# Function pointer array, passing values defined in array

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, function-pointers

I'm trying to define an array of function pointers, where each function contains an `int` parameter. I'm also trying to set the value of that int parameter in the array declaration

So I have a `TIMED_TASK` struct, that will hold the function pointer and value I want to pass

```
typedef struct
{
   void (*proc)(int);  
   int delayMsec;     
} TIMED_TASK;
```

Then I have an array of `TIMED_TASK`s like this

```
static const TIMED_TASK attractSequence[] =
{
    { LightsOn, 1000 },
    { LightsOff, 500 },
    { EndSequence, 0 }
};
```

And I'd like it to call each of those functions in turn, passing the delay value to each function. This is where I expect I have the wrong syntax (I'm still learning C). I seemingly don't hit my `LightsOn()` routine at all

```
void loop() // It's an arduino project :)
{
  attractSequence[sequence];
  sequence++;
}

void LightsOn(int pause)
{
  // I do not hit this routine for some reason?
  Serial.print("LIGHTS ON"); 
  Serial.print(pause);
}

void LightsOff(int pause)
{
  Serial.print("LIGHTS OFF");
  Serial.print(pause);
}
```

It's entirely possible I'm taking the wrong approach here, but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to achieve. Any advice very welcome!

Comment: Are you sure this is straight up C? This looks like an embedded dialect like the arduino language.

Comment: Correct, it's an arduino project. But I believe the syntax should be the same as C?

Comment: It's not, `Serial.print(pause)` is invalid c, not entirely invalid but as it is in your code it seems to be. Also, you are never calling the function through the pointer, where do i expect it to be called in the posted code?

Comment: Arduino is not **C**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to go through each item of `attractSequence` only once, you can use:

```
void loop()
{
   int count = sizeof(attractSequence)/sizeof(attractSequence[0]);
   for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i )
   {
     attractSequence[i].proc(attractSequence[i].delayMsec);
   }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. The syntax I needed was attractSequence[sequence].proc(attractSequence[sequence].delayMsec). Makes perfect sense now that I see it